# Attach to running container dockerode

Tags: javascript, docker, dockerode

Trying to ssh into running container using dockerode. I want to run a container with commands like 'node dist/server.js' then after container is started ssh it into it and run bash by default. Looked at all the examples for attach a container but all examples are first creating the container with CMD as bash and then just attaching it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `docker exec -it $your_container_id bash`.

The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) provide more info on what it does and all the options. But it should work with whatever format you Dockerfile has.

Comment: I want to do using dockerode library not docker cli client.